# Can someone find the colored version of this Jojo manga panel of Jolyene using Stone Free whilst near/attached to a car?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

Can someone find the colored version of this *Jojo* manga panel? It's (I think) Jolyene using Stone Free whilst near/attached to a car. All I need is the colored version for a project I'm working on.

[image: manga panel described above]

Comment: Do you know which chapter this is from?

Comment: By "the colored version", did you mean the official colored manga, or fan-colored? Mentioning the chapter number surely helps those who want to help you though.